# Setting up an email reminder based on dates in excel sheet

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, excel, microsoft-forms

I've been asked to find a way to have an excel spreadsheet (that will be updated often) send an email to the email address from a column, as well as on a specific date according from another column. But hoping for it to do it automatically given that it is about 500 rows long. If I need to open a program every morning, I'm willing to do that. I also need the email to grab the name of the coordinator from a specific column in the sheet, a number from another column, as well as being able to add a message to the email. I'm willing to use anything within sharepoint.

So basically, when November 16 (Column H) hits, it will automatically send an email (that is in Column G) like below:

Hello (Name from Column F),

(Number from Column A) is within 130 days.

Thank you,

XXXXXXXX

Is this at all possible within sharepoint?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to set up an email reminder based on dates in an Excel sheet using Power Automate. You can create a flow that is triggered when a date in the specified column is approaching, and then sends an email to the email address in the specified column. You can also include the name of the coordinator from a specific column, a number from another column, and a message in the email. Here are the steps to create the flow:

1. Import your Excel sheet to a SharePoint list.
2. Open Power Automate and create a new flow.
3. Select the trigger "**Recurrence**" and set the interval to run the flow daily.
4. Add a "**Get items**" action to get all the items from the list or library.
5. Add a "**Filter array**" action to filter the items based on the date column. You can use an expression like `items('Get_items')?['body/value']?['Date_column_name']` to get the date value from the items.
6. Add a "**Apply to each**" action to loop through the filtered items.
7. Inside the loop, add a "**Condition**" action to check if the date is approaching.
8. You can use an expression like `lessOrEquals(item()?['Date_column_name'], addDays(utcNow(), 7))` to check if the date is within 7 days.
9. Inside the "If true" branch of the condition, add a "**Send an email**" action to send the email to the email address in the specified column. You can use expressions like `item()?['Email_column_name']` to get the email address, `item()?['Name_column_name']` to get the name of the coordinator, and `item()?['Number_column_name']` to get the number.
10. In the email body, you can include the message and use expressions like `concat('Hello ', item()?['Name_column_name'], ',\n\n', item()?['Number_column_name'], ' is within 130 days.\n\nThank you,\n\nXXXXXXXX')` to generate the message.